# Django OneToOneField is causing IntegrityError at /submissions/submit/ NOT NULL constraint failed: submissions_submissiondata.submission_code_id

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, one-to-one

I'm trying to implement a model in such a way that a User can have multiple submissions, and a Submission has only one object of type SubmissionData.

On the template, user will upload a PDF file, this PDF will be parsed, some info associated with that submission will be stored in the SubmissionData, and the file and some main information will be associated with the SubmissionData

here is the **models.py**:

```
class Submission(models.Model):

    submission_user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User',
                                        related_name='submissions',
                                        on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    submission_file = models.FileField(upload_to='media/')

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        user_submission = str(self.submission_user.username).lower()
        user_submission = user_submission + '/' + str(timezone.now())
        return user_submission

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_at']


class SubmissionData(models.Model):

    submission_code = models.OneToOneField(Submission,
                                           related_name='data',
                                           on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    uuid = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)

    patiente_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)

    patiente_age = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)

    patient_gender = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
```

and on my **views.py**:

```
class SubmissionCreateView(CreateView, LoginRequiredMixin):

    form_class = SubmissionForm
    template_name = 'submissions/submission_create.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('submissions:list')

    def proccess_submission_data(self):
       parser = PDFParser('path-to-pdf').parse()
       data_obj = parser.get_result()
       submission_data = self.enconde(data_obj)

       self.object.save()
       submission_data.save()

    def enconde(self, data_obj):
        submission_data = SubmissionData(submission_code=self.object,
                                         uuid=data_obj.uuid,
                                         patiente_name=data_obj.patiente_name,
                                         patiente_age=data_obj.patiente_age,
                                         patient_gender=data_obj.patient_gender)
        return submission_data

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.submission_user = self.request.user
        self.proccess_submission_data()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

For some reason I'm getting the following error:
[image]

And the error is triggered on those lines:
[image]

Does anyone know what could be causing those errors?

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same problem. Did you have an empty db when you make these changes to your model ?

Comment: Yes, I do have and empty db! I have solve the issue!

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the issue, insted of `submission_data = SubmissionData(..)`. I have use the Django's built in to create the objects `submission_data = SubmissionData.objects.create(...)` and after that It worked fine.